# Css3 animation SVG not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, safari

I'm trying to get a simple CSS3 animation on a SVG. Till now it works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not on Safari.

I added `@-webkit-keyframes` so it should work, but it doesn't.
I just started to code, so I may have gone wrong everywhere but I really need help!

```css
#EYEBROW2 {
  -webkit-animation: MoveEyebrow2 3s linear 2.2s 1 both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 57% 10%;
  animation: MoveEyebrow2 3s linear 2.2s 1 both;
  transform-origin: 57% 10%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes MoveEyebrow2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes MoveEyebrow2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(5.5px) rotate(4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="500" height="100">
    <g id="EYEBROW2"> <g> <path class="st9" d="M415.4,26.1l-8.6-0.5C406.3,21.8,415.6,26.2,415.4,26.1z" stroke="black" fill="black"/> </g> </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

But if I try to run the animations everything goes wrong! It's like it doesn't recognize the `transform-origin` point.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you talking about the mobile browser, as I just tested in the desktop version of safari and its working perfectly fine. [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/RQmmWv). Also, seems like you didn't mention the id `EYEBROW2` to your `<div>`. Is that just a typo or you actually missed it?

Comment: i'm talking about the desktop version. Actually the css is inside the svg file since i'm animated the signle path. tha svg image is a face and i have to animate the different parts.

Comment: In order to do that i worked inside the svg. so the id="EYEBROW2" is referred to the path inside the svg that corrspond to the eyebrow     
    
<g id="EYEBROW2">
<g>
<path class="st9" d="M415.4,26.1l-8.6-0.5C406.3,21.8,415.6,26.2,415.4,26.1z"/>
</g>
</g>

Comment: What i want is that the eyebrow rotates in its center, but while in chrome this is actually working, with safari it just takes another point to rotate around.

Comment: Could you provide a codepen link please?

Comment: https://codepen.io/saraboschin/pen/qxzbgP

Comment: for the svg file there the download link in the html, i didn't know how to attach it ):

Comment: Please see this [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/yvdpxL?editors=1100) where I have managed to make a working copy of your code. You could tweak the animation sets to get the desired output as the same works in safari as well. Please have a look and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yr8o80npxzkmsk3/Code.zip?dl=0  still not working on Safari. it's like the 'trasform-origin' point it's different between the two browsers